# How to add AccessDataBaseEngine without installing

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have built an application which wants to access Excel page, it works fine only if Access Database Engine is installed in machine, Now the question is How can I make the application work properly without installing Access Database Engine in other machine or how to make it to install as dependency without installing seperatly but gets installed automatically. I am using 1 click setup to develop the Setup.

Comment: So you're using the Access Database Engine to access and Excel document?

Comment: Also, is this a desktop or web application?

Comment: Ya, I am using Access Database Engine to access Excel Document, and its Desktop application

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Access Database Engine, then I think you'll have to include their [re-distributable installer](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) with your install package.  Depending on what you're doing, if the users have Excel installed already you could just use the [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) instead.